# Como transformar cada algarismo de um número em um elemento de um vetor no R?

Tags: r

Por exemplo:

```
numero <- 516481
```

como posso transformar cada algarismo desse número em um elemento de um vetor, para poder acessá-los por index?
Pois se `numero` fosse um vetor com cada elemento sendo um algarismo eu teria:

```
> print(numero)
[1] 5 1 5 4 8 1
```

E se quisesse acessar o número `8`, por exemplo, bastaria lhe requisitar pela sua posição:

```
> numero[5]
[1] 8
```

Como estou lidando com números de 80 dígitos, fazer à mão com a função concatenar `c(5,1,6,4,8,1)` é inviável.
Saibam que meu objetivo maior é poder acessar os números por índice, mesmo que não seja através de um vetor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode converter para caracter e usar `strsplit`, convertendo depois de volta para número:

```
numero <- 516481*10^9

algarismos <- as.integer(strsplit(as.character(format(numero, scientific = FALSE)), "")[[1]])

> algarismos
[1] 5 1 6 4 8 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

`strsplit` retorna uma lista; o `[[1]]` indica para pegar o primeiro (e único, no caso) elemento e retorná-lo como vetor.

`format(numero, scientific = FALSE)` evita erro por uso de notação científica ao converter para caractere.

Comment: Carlos, seu método funciona muito bem com números de poucos algarismos, mas a coisa fica caótica com números grandes. Atribuindo `numero <- 1111111111111111111111111111111111`  seguido de `algarismos <- as.integer(strsplit(as.character(numero), "")[[1]])` já percebe-se que algo saiu errado pela mensagem `Warning message:
NAs introduzidos por coerção` do console. E, ao pedir para ver o conteúdo de algarismos, com  `> algarismos` o console me retorna `[1]  1 NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA  3  3` Perceba que não só NAs foram introduzidos como algarismos 3 que nunca existiram

Comment: E mais, a saída não contém a quantidade de itens que deveria. `numero` possuia cerca de 30 algarismos e o vetor `algarismos` não tem nem 20 itens Alguma ideia do motivo de isso acontecer?

Comment: Atualizando: retirando o pedido `as.integer` para conversão em inteiro, temos: `algarismos <- strsplit(as.character(numero), "")[[1]]` e `algarismos` fica com o conteúdo: `[1] "1" "." "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "e" "+" "3" "3"` agora está claro de onde os NAs vieram, aparentemente o R salva números muito grandes na forma de potência, o que acaba sendo um problema nessa situação.

Comment: Veja a ajuda para `as.character`, é só usar `format`. Atualizei a resposta para incluir essa opção.